# Timezone confusion in Ruby on Rails 4.0, Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql-9.1

I have a query that hits my database and it returns a column of dates.  the output of this query looks something like this in psql:

Query:

```
SELECT (by_event.event_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::DATE as event_date from events as by_event;
```

Output:

```
event_date   
------------
 2012-11-15 
 2012-11-16
 2012-11-17
```

I run my SQL query in Rails with this:

```
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql) 

results.each do |result|
  puts result.inspect
end
```

This unfortunately prints out:

```
[{\"event_date\"=>\"2012-11-16\"}, {...}]
```

All of the dates are one day ahead of what they should be!

Obviously this is timezone related, but I am not sure how to fix it.  How do I get Rails to stop bumping up the date?

Comment: `config/application.rb` check what `config.time_zone` is set to. If its not set, set it to your desired time zone and things should be fine.

Comment: I have tried calling `Time.zone = "EST"` and `Time.zone = "UTC"` with no change in results. just before running the query.

Answer (score 1):

For future people, here is what I did to fix this:

```
SELECT  ((by_event.event_date) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York')::DATE as event_date,
```

Ugly, but it works.